# Window modal QFileDialog pushing parent to background after exec()

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I stripped my problem down to what it necessary, so don't mind that is does nothing useful as shown here.

I have my `MainWindow` which is a `QMainWindow` with a `QPushButton` inside, and I connected the `clicked()` signal of that button to the following slot of the `QMainWindow`:

```
void MainWindow::followingSlot()
{
    OpenFileDialog(this);
}
```

`OpenFileDialog` is a free function:

```
void OpenFileDialog(QWidget * inParent)
{
    QFileDialog dialog(inParent, "caption");
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
    dialog.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    dialog.exec();
}
```

It all works fine, until I have 2 or more `MainWindow`s in play. Then, at the end of the `QFileDialog::exec()` call, the current `MainWindow` is pushed back one place in the 'focus stack' and the `MainWindow` that was second becomes activated and jumps to the foreground. I'd like the window that was active and in front to stay active and in front.

I can of course adapt `OpenFileDialog` to the following:

```
void OpenFileDialog(QWidget * inParent)
{
    QFileDialog dialog(inParent, "caption");
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
    dialog.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    dialog.exec();
    inParent->raise();
    inParent->activateWindow();
}
```

That brings my `MainWindow` back to the front, but you can see the windows switching places briefly.

I found no similar problems via Google, QtCentre or SO. Is there a way to stop this behavior and keep the focus on the `MainWindow` that had focus?

I'm working with Qt 4.8 on Mac.

**EDIT:**
I found that it's not the current `MainWindow` that gets pushed back, it's the `MainWindow` that is second in the stack, that gets pulled to the front. If I start with the left stack, I'll end up with the right stack (top being in front, bottom being at the back):

```
current MainWindow    other MainWindow   raise() current MainWindow
other application  -> current MainWindow ------> other MainWindow
other MainWindow      other application          other application
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the modality to Qt::ApplicationModal. This way the FileDialog is modal to the entire application, and not just the parent window.

Comment: Then the problem does not happen, but I don't want the FileDialog to be application modal. I want it to be window modal (especially since this results in a sheet dialog on Mac).